# Testing joins in Kafka Streams

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a question about to testing kafak streams, particulary testing joins inside kafka streams.
i have a small use case with an employee which I want to join with an insurance. The output will be an enriched employee with the name of the insurance. The reference will be the insuranceIdx in the employee.

Here is my topology for the use case:

```
public class EnrichEmployeesTopoplogy {


    public void createTopology(final StreamsBuilder builder) {

        final Serde<EnrichedEmployee> enrichedEmployeeSerde = SerdeFactory.serdeForEnrichedEmployee();
        final Serde<Insurance> insuranceSerde = SerdeFactory.serdeForInsurance();
        final Serde<Employee> employeeSerde = SerdeFactory.serdeForEmployee();

        // read the incomming employee events in a stream
        final KStream<String, Employee> employeeStream =
                builder.stream("employees", Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), employeeSerde));

        // rekey the incomming employee stream that it will have the same key as the insurance.
        final KStream<String, Employee> rekeyedEmployeeStream
                = employeeStream.selectKey((k, v) -> String.valueOf(v.getInsuranceIdx()));


        // read the incomming insurance events in a table
        final KTable<String, Insurance> insuranceTable = builder.table("insurances",
                Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), insuranceSerde));

        // create the value joiner
        ValueJoiner<Employee, Insurance, EnrichedEmployee> employeeJoiner =
                (employee, insurance) ->
                        EnrichedEmployee.builder()
                                .idx(employee.getIdx())
                                .email(employee.getEmail())
                                .insuranceName(insurance.getName())
                                .build();

        // create the joined with 
        final Joined<String, Employee, Insurance> joined = Joined.with(Serdes.String(), employeeSerde, insuranceSerde);


        rekeyedEmployeeStream.join(insuranceTable, employeeJoiner, joined)
                .to("enriched-employees", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), enrichedEmployeeSerde));


    }
}
```

When I test this behaviour with an real Kafka, it will work as it should.
Now I've write a unit test using kafka-streams-test-utils

Here is my test code:

```
class EnrichedEmployeeTopologyTest {


    private TopologyTestDriver testDriver;
    private TestInputTopic<String, Employee> inputTopicEmployees;
    private TestInputTopic<String, Insurance> inputTopicInsurances;
    private TestOutputTopic<String, EnrichedEmployee> outputTopicEnrichedEmployees;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {

        final Serde<EnrichedEmployee> enrichedEmployeeSerde = SerdeFactory.serdeForEnrichedEmployee();
        final Serde<Insurance> insuranceSerde = SerdeFactory.serdeForInsurance();
        final Serde<Employee> employeeSerde = SerdeFactory.serdeForEmployee();

        final Properties streamsConfiguration = new Properties();
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "test01");
        streamsConfiguration.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "dummy:9092");

        final EnrichEmployeesTopoplogy enrichEmployeesTopoplogy = new EnrichEmployeesTopoplogy();
        final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        enrichEmployeesTopoplogy.createTopology(builder);

        final Topology topology = builder.build();

        testDriver = new TopologyTestDriver(topology, streamsConfiguration);
        inputTopicEmployees = testDriver.createInputTopic("employees", Serdes.String().serializer(), employeeSerde.serializer());
        inputTopicInsurances = testDriver.createInputTopic("insurances", Serdes.String().serializer(), insuranceSerde.serializer());
        outputTopicEnrichedEmployees = testDriver.createOutputTopic("enriched-employees", Serdes.String().deserializer(), enrichedEmployeeSerde.deserializer());

    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
        testDriver.close();
    }

    @Test
    void createTopology() {
        final String employeeIdx = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        final String insuranceIdx = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

        final Employee employee = Employee.builder().idx(employeeIdx).email("foo1@bar.de").insuranceIdx(insuranceIdx).build();
        final Insurance insurance = Insurance.builder().idx(insuranceIdx).name("insurance 01").build();


        inputTopicEmployees.pipeInput(employee.getIdx(), employee);
        inputTopicInsurances.pipeInput(insurance.getIdx(), insurance);

        Assertions.assertEquals(true, !outputTopicEnrichedEmployees.isEmpty());
    }
}
```

The result will be that the assertion alway will fail.

I've tried to experiment a little with the stream configuration values. But nothing will change.
My assumption is that it could be a timing problem within the test.
Can anybody help me about this problem?

Best Regards
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

In Kafka Streams - Stream-Table joins are only triggered by new incoming KStream records; incoming KTable records only update the KTable.  In your test here, can you switch the order of calls and execute `inputTopicInsurances.pipeInput` first, then the `inputTopicEmployees.pipeInput` method, and see if that works?